# When does the inverse convolution of a distribution exist?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, convolution

I have an equation of the form
$$F_1 * F_2 = a \cdot F_3 - b \cdot F_4$$
where all the $F$'s are cumulative distribution functions and $a$ and $b$ are some constants, and I want to solve for $F_2$. In order to do this, I would like to find the inverse of $F_1$ with respect to convolution, i.e. another CDF $F_1^{-1}$ such that
$$F_1 * F_1^{-1} = \delta.$$
However, such inverses do not always exist. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Algebraic_properties) has the following unhelpful remark

> Some distributions have an inverse element for the convolution

but says nothing about which distributions.

There are a couple of related questions here on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560476/inverse-convolution-of-a-distribution) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896704/is-the-convolution-operation-some-kind-of-group-operation),
but I don't see any mention of what distributions allow for an inverse for convolution.

So my question is: for what kind of distributions does there exist an inverse element with respect to convolution?

Comment: As usual : $T$ is the limit in the sense of distributions of $T_n(x) = (T e^{- \pi x^2/ n^2}) 
 \ast n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2}$ whose Fourier transform is $\hat{T}_n(\xi) =
 (\hat{T} \ast n^2 e^{- \pi n^2 \xi^2} ) e^{-\pi \xi^2/n^2 }$ so that $\frac{e^{- \pi x^2/n^2}}{\hat{T}_n(\xi)} \ast n e^{- \pi n^2 x^2}$ as well as its inverse Fourier transform is well-defined.